# Ubunutu Application (Eclipse, Matlab..) that minimizes when execution

Tags: eclipse, window, matlab

When I run a program on Eclipse or Matlab, it switches to another opened application and I have to go to the app (Eclipse or Matlab) every execution. Is there any solution please?